# Please verify the Facebook Page of Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, facebook

The Stack Overflow [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/officialstackoverflow?pnref=story) appears to be unverified. (There is no blue check mark beside the name. Example: [Facebook's own profile](https://www.facebook.com/facebook) and [Wikipedia's profile](https://www.facebook.com/wikipedia) are verified.)

If at all possible, please [verify](https://www.facebook.com/help/100168986860974) the page so we can be confident that it is the correct official page of Stack Overflow.

Comment: [*Right now, we're only accepting verification requests from Pages that represent celebrities, public figures, sports teams, media and entertainment.*](https://www.facebook.com/help/100168986860974). I don't see *web sites* listed there.

Comment: So as to *why* they haven't been verified: it doesn't look like Facebook accepts requests for verification for the type of entity that the Stack Overflow Facebook page represents. It is not something you can just obtain, at any rate.

Comment: @Martijn Not sure what you mean, SO is my media and entertainment while at work. :)

Comment: On the other hand, there appears to be a precedent. [Yahoo Answers **is** verified](https://www.facebook.com/yahooanswers), so perhaps Stack Overflow should try and apply.

Comment: Actually there are bunches of Websites that got verification. Like: ask.fm, techcrunch, thenextweb, theverge etc. Then why not SO? I asked this only for my curiosity.

Comment: stack overflow is a celebrity.  stack overflow is a public figure.  stack overflow is a sports team.  stack overflow is the media.  stack overflow is entertainment.  you'll always get a warm welcome at stack overflow.  welcome to stack overflow.  this is stack overflow.com.  welcome.  this is stack overflow.com.  welcome to stack overflow.com.  you can do anything at stack overflow.com.  anything.  the only limit is yourself. welcome to stack overflow.com. [..](http://zombo.com/)[.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qxWwEPeUuAg)

Comment: "Actually there are bunches of Websites that got verification"... as it says at FB, "right **now** we are only accepting..."

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think that StackOverflow can very clearly be classified as some form of media, perhaps in the same sense you might classify [Wikipedia](https://www.facebook.com/wikipedia) (which is also verified) as media.

Comment: @Yakk, Huh, what's with the zombo.com ?

Comment: @Pacerier: maybe turn on sound before visiting?

Comment: Considering FB developers also visit and benefit from SO, I don't see why they wouldn't like to verify SO's page.

Comment: What's the point of being verified? A page is just a page... How can I be sure that the guys behind StackOverflow.com are StackExchange? Why should I even care? Plus, anyone can be verified for no reason. I have friends who are verified just because they asked for it at the right moment, so what's the point? It's just a tag that says absolutely nothing.

Comment: SO is mostly invisible to the general public. That's why there's a Yahoo Answers that is verified.

Comment: What about youtube? even myspace has a tick haha

Comment: Please don't ever go on Facebook. Let them come to us. We don't need FB fake publicity stunts. http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-do-i-delete-my-facebook-account

Comment: Why would you ever visit stackoverflow on facebook? I am confused :P

Comment: Just for sharing and tagging SO related post on FB. :P @wigy

Comment: @Zerotoinfinity: I don't see how a verification mark on one of Stack Overflow's official social media accounts is in any way related to your personal paranoia and website visiting preferences.

Comment: @wigy May be we wont visit SO page on facebook often, but it may help the people out there to identify the real SO facebook page among the [auto generated one](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Stack-Overflow/105665906133609?fref=ts) /fake ones to follow or like it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'd consider SO as _media_.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit Facebook supports free-booting and their cookies and privacy policies are scary. I'll never be surprised if one day I'll see Facebook keylogger in my task manager. Recently, one of the news paper in my region provided proof that some "political leader" purchased likes from FB. http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/01/05/buy-facebook-likes_n_4544800.html 
 May be these are the reason people don't like it (including me) :)

Comment: @AnujTripathi: Still not seeing the relevance. Keep the tinfoil anti-corporation hate out of this. If you don't like Facebook then don't use it, but that has _nothing_ to do with this question. And, for future reference, statements like _"I'll never be surprised if one day I'll see Facebook keylogger in my task manager"_ make it hard to take you seriously.

Comment: @Pacerier Looks like Yakk has tried to [parse HTML with regular expressions...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/)

Comment: It's called "page".

Comment: Wow just thousands of comments that directly answer the question butnot even a single answer

Comment: *Please don't ever go on Facebook.* @Zerotoinfinity Unless the page the OP linked to is a fake, it's already too late for that.

Comment: @BSMP :) Actually, I did click on that !

Answer (score 4):

Alternative: If the powers that be don't agree that web sites are media, Stack Overflow could provide a list of their  official social media accounts. The footer of [the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/?blb=1) only links to the official Stack Exchange accounts but the bottom of the [about page](https://stackoverflow.com/company/about) for the company could be a logical place to put all of the official accounts.